# Как можно прочитать такую запись

Tags: javascript

```js
function marry(man, woman) {
  woman.husband = man;
  man.wife = woman;

  return {
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  }
}

var family = marry({
  name: "Василий"
}, {
  name: "Мария"
});
```

1. Создается функция marry с двумя параметрами man, woman
2. woman получает ссылку на man
3. man получает ссылку на woman
4. Создан объект который возвращается в переменную family и становится объектом
5. В man хранится **Василий** woman хранится **Мария**
6. Верно ?

Comment: почти все верно, хотя некоторые фразы звучат странно

Comment: @ThisMan :(((((